# SQL query takes much time to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Candidate` with 43,437 rows of data, which have been created by many employees.

I want to get a report in which I get each employee's individual created candidate in a period of 7 days.. For that I executed the following query.

```
select E.Id, E.Employeename,
(select 
    count(C.ID) 
from 
    candidate C 
where 
    CreatorID = E.ID  
    and C.Createdate between Convert(DateTime,'19/07/2014',103) And Convert(DateTime,'26/07/2014',103))

From Employee E
```

where `E.ID` is employee's ID from `Employee` table..

But the above query takes around 2 minutes to execute.. I didn't done indexing in `Candidate` table..

How to make this query execute within few seconds..?

Comment: What is alias `E` in  your query?

Comment: I would look into creating some indexes - one on `CreateDate` (and possibly including `CreatorID`, too) since you're using that in your `WHERE` clause, and possibly one on `C.ID` (or maybe just add this to the first index you create as an *included* column)

Comment: @marc_s, is it possible to add indexes for 'CreateDate', as it is already created table.. If so, can you let me know how to do that..?

Comment: Sure! `CREATE INDEX IX_Candidate_CreateDate ON dbo.Candidate(CreateDate);` should do the trick

Comment: Your above query is syntactically incorrect (the alias `E` is undefined).  Please fix the query before asking about performance.

Comment: I've update the query completely..

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description of the problem, the query should look like:

```
select Creator_id, count(C.ID) 
from candidate C 
where C.Createdate between Convert(DateTime, '19/07/2014', 103) And 
                           Convert(DateTime, '26/07/2014', 103)
group by Creator_id;
```

(This assumes that there is a foreign key relationship between `candidate.Creator_id` and `Employees.id`.)

The best index for this query is a covering index that has the three columns mentioned in the query:

```
create index idx_candidate_createddate_creator_id_id on candidate(created_date, creator_id, id);
```